# RegEx Return All Matches

Tags: php, regex

I have this string:

```
Sales History Book/Page Sale Date Deed Type Sale Condition Sale Price 24604 - 001199/2/2014TD -     TAX DEED9 - PUBLIC UTILITY OR GOVERNMENT$10,000.0017178 - 004422/28/2005QC - QUIT CLAIM DEED2 - PARTIAL INTEREST$0.0010482 - 0076612/17/1998WD - WARRANTY DEED0 - VALID SALE FMV$68,800.0005088 - 0033910/19/1984WD - WARRANTY DEED0 - VALID SALE FMV$48,425.00          Sales which occurred prior to January 1 of this year were used to establish values for the current year.
```

I am looking to pull out each sale, which can be seen formatted as DDDDD - DDDDD [bunch of characters, then .DD

I tried this:

```
$regEx = "/\d{5} - \d{5}.+.\d{2}/";
preg_match($regEx,$salesString,$match);
print_r($match);
```

but it returns everything from 24604 until the final .00 before the word Sales.  Ideally my regex would return four separate rows, so I can then parse each rows more granularly.

What change would you recommend?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**3 changes**

- make `.+` non greedy as `.+?`

  Required as `.+` is greedy and try to match as many characters as possible. So it matches from the start `24604` and conitnues greedily until the last match `.00`
- escape `.` as `\.`

  `.` in regex matches any character. Inorder to match a `.` we should escape the special meaning so that it litterally matches a `.`
- use `match_all`

  performs a global regex match and retrievs all part of string that matches the regex. Where as `match` will retrieve only the first match

The regex can be

```
\d{5} - \d{5}.+?\.\d{2}
```

**Example :** http://regex101.com/r/zX8cZ0/1

**Example usage**

```
$re = "/\\d{5} - \\d{5}.+?\\.\\d{2}/";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Will give output as

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
              [0] => 24604 - 001199/2/2014TD - TAX DEED9 - PUBLIC UTILITY OR GOVERNMENT$10,000.00 
              [1] => 17178 - 004422/28/2005QC - QUIT CLAIM DEED2 - PARTIAL INTEREST$0.00 
              [2] => 10482 - 0076612/17/1998WD - WARRANTY DEED0 - VALID SALE FMV$68,800.00     
              [3] => 05088 - 0033910/19/1984WD - WARRANTY DEED0 - VALID SALE FMV$48,425.00 ) 
      )
```

Comment: Yes, that got it.  Would you mind explaining why these changes are important?  It would help me learn...

Comment: @JoshFeingold I have edited my answer. Hope that its clear :)